# How to force the use of gzip behind the reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, gzip, reverse-proxy

I want to use nginx as a reverse proxy and I really want to optimize the communication between nginx and our backend. The payloads we are transferring are about 1Mb of text when not compressed and the reverse proxy and the server are in different data centers.

My understanding and the tests I have done show me that the compression between reverse proxy and the backends depends on the client request.

But this is not optimal because if the client is not configured to use gzip when reading the reverse proxy response, there is no reason to not use gzip between nginx and the backend server.

I would like to force the communication between the reverse proxy and the backend to use gzip, even if the client did not request it.

I managed to make it works but I am not sure it is well configured, especially because I need to force the `Accept` header.

My idea was to force `Accept-Encoding: gzip` when proxying a request, and to use gunzip if the client did not request gzip.

```
upstream backend {
    server fqdn:443;
    keepalive 32;
}

server {
  listen   8080;

  gzip on;
  gunzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types 
        text/css
        text/javascript
        text/xml
        text/plain
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json;

  proxy_buffering "off";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header "Accept-Encoding" "gzip";
    proxy_pass   https://backend;
  }
}
```

Is it normal that I must force this header?

Why the `gzip_proxied any` is not enough?

Thanks in advance